# How to merge two objects in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know how to merge objects using mongoose.

For example say my document is:

```
{
    a: {
        x: 2,
        y: 3
    }
}
```

and I have an object:

```
{
    x: 3,
    z: 5
}
```

I would like to merge them so that I now have:

```
{
    a: {
        x: 3,
        y: 3,
        z: 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Object.assign(doc1.a, doc2.toObject())
doc1.save()
```

But you might want to use `delete doc2._id` before merging it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

Example:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = Object.assign({c: 4, d: 5}, object1);
console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
```

Or alternatively, you can use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = {c: 4, d: 5, ...object1}
console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers regarding `Object.assign()` didn't work for me, but what you can do is using the `spread` operator like this:

```
 const user = await User.findById(12345); // your Mongoose model
 const existingProperties = user.properties.toObject(); // existing properties from the user
 const providedProperties = { a: 1 }; // new properties to be inserted/overwritten

 // merge the two objects, this will overwrite properties in existingProperties if
 // they are provided in the providedProperties object, otherwise they will be attached
 const mergedProperties = { ...existingProperties, ...providedProperties };

 user.set({ properties: mergedProperties });
 const updatedUser = await user.save();
```